# Regular expression to match both csv fields

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have data that can look like this (notice the PM after SPX):

```
11 Dec 1650.00 (SPXPM1130L1650-E),1.90,0.0,1.35,2.30,0,10,11 Dec 1650.00 (SPXPM1130X1650-E),0.0,0.0,376.20,380.00,0,0,
```

or like this (notice no -E, W, or PM):

```
14 Oct 800.00 (SPX1418J800),0.0,0.0,1067.10,1071.40,0,0,14 Oct 800.00 (SPX1418V800),0.09,0.0,0.0,0.05,0,25,
```

or data that can look like this (notice the extra W after the SPX):

```
11 Jan 1075.00 (SPXW1128A1075-E),0.0,0.0,215.30,217.00,0,0,11 Jan 1075.00 (SPXW1128M1075-E),0.05,-0.10,0.05,0.10,10,15535,
```

I am using the following regular expression in Python to get the entire first comma separated field of the data (i.e., `"14 Oct 800.00 (SPX1418J800)"`):

```
spx_symbol = re.compile("\\(SPX(1[0-9])([0-9]{2})([A-Z])([0-9]{3,4})-E\\)")
```

This works fine with the second data format above (the one that has the W), but fails with the first when there is *NOT* an extra "W" and some that don't have an extra -E, or the PM, **when I try to get the tokens from a fixed spot. See the functions below**.

When I feed it the first line above I get:

```
spx_symbol.split(line)
```

This is the way these tokens after `split` are used and only the original regex works some of the time:

```
def ExpiryMonth(s):
    """
    SPX contract months
    """
    call_months = "ABCDEFGHIJKL"
    put_months = "MNOPQRSTUVWX"

    try:
        m = call_months.index(s)
    except ValueError:
        m = put_months.index(s)

    return m

#spx_symbol = re.compile("\\(SPX(1[0-9])([0-9]{2})([A-Z])([0-9]{3,4})-E\\)") WORKS SOME OF TIME
spx_symbol = re.compile("\((SPX(1[0-9])([0-9]{2})([A-Z])([0-9]{3,4})(-E)?\\))")

def parseSPX(s):
    """
    Parse an SPX quote string, return expiry date and strike
    """
    tokens = spx_symbol.split(s)

    if len(tokens) == 1:
        return {'dtExpiry': None, 'strike': -1}

    year = 2000 + int(tokens[1])
    day = int(tokens[2])
    month = ExpiryMonth(tokens[3])
    strike = float(tokens[4])

    dtExpiry = datetime.date(year, month, day)

    return ({'dtExpiry': dtExpiry, 'strike': strike})
```

Comment: Are you using a regex to parse the csv file? If so, why aren't you using the csv module instead? If not, why does it matter that these are fields in a csv file? What are you *actually* trying to do, here?

Comment: what data exactly do you want from those lines?

Comment: @AirThomas, based on the question, I answered it assuming that he just needed a portion of the first field. If you need more than that Ivan, I also recommend looking at the `csv` module

Comment: looking at your sample data, can't you just use `re.findall(r'\(SPX.{7,12}\)', text)` to get all matched results?

Comment: @ivan, why do you think you need a regular expression? You file is delimited by commas, you want the data before the first comma so as I have shown you in my answer just use a normal split or the csv module

Comment: [This blog post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) should be required reading before posting regex questions.

Comment: Sorry my original question was innacurate. Please see the text now. I need to extract the strike and expiration from the contents of the first field. Hence the regex.

Comment: I know I can probably hack it and hardwire it so that I can handle all cases, but it seems that regex is more elegant. Air Thomas I agree with that article.

Answer (score 1):

*I have a regular expression in python like this that tries to get the entire first comma separated field of the data. In other words, e.g., "14 Oct 800.00 (SPX1418J800)"*

Just use `split`, splitting on a comma and getting the first element, you don't need re:

```
s="14 Oct 800.00 (SPX1418J800),0.0,0.0,1067.10,1071.40,0,0,14 Oct 800.00 (SPX1418V800),0.09,0.0,0.0,0.05,0,25"

print(s.split(",",1)[0])
14 Oct 800.00 (SPX1418J800)


s1 = "11 Jan 1075.00 (SPXW1128A1075-E),0.0,0.0,215.30,217.00,0,0,11 Jan 1075.00 (SPXW1128M1075-E),0.05,-0.10,0.05,0.10,10,15535,"
print(s1.split(",",1)[0])
11 Jan 1075.00 (SPXW1128A1075-E)
```

If you just want what is inside the parens which according to the output in your question you don't you can split again:

```
s = "14 Oct 800.00 (SPX1418J800),0.0,0.0,1067.10,1071.40,0,0,14 Oct 800.00 (SPX1418V800),0.09,0.0,0.0,0.05,0,25"

print(s.split(",",1)[0].rsplit(" ",1)[-1])
(SPX1418J800)
```

Or simply use the csv module:

```
import  csv
with open(my.csv) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    for line in reader:
        print(line[0])
14 Oct 800.00 (SPX1418J800)
11 Jan 1075.00 (SPXW1128A1075-E)
```

Comment: See the added text in original post. I need to call parseSPX and extract strike and expiry, not just the contents of the first field. My fault for not being clear. Sorry.

Comment: can you add what you expect as output as it is still not clear what you expect

Answer (score 0):

This is the RegEx I utilized:

```
"\((SPXW?(1[0-9])([0-9]{2})([A-Z])([0-9]{3,4})(-E)?\))"
```

You can see it functioning here. I am printing the whole matched portion

```
>>> first_fields = [
... "14 Oct 800.00 (SPX1418J800)",
... "11 Jan 1075.00 (SPXW1128A1075-E)"
... ]
>>> spx_symbols = re.compile("\((SPXW?(1[0-9])([0-9]{2})([A-Z])([0-9]{3,4})(-E)?\))")
>>> for f in first_fields:
...     print spx_symbols.search(f).group(0)
...
(SPX1418J800)
(SPXW1128A1075-E)
```

Changes I made:

```
W? - This looks for an optional "W"
(-E)? - This looks for an optional "-E"
```

Comment: I tried your new regex but it doesn't work. However, I did not have a complete question so you answered correctly, but not to the ultimate question I have. See modified post.